# Difference between shape drawable and canvas.draw, workaround?

Tags: android, android-canvas, shapedrawable

I'm using two ways to display buttons and edit texts in my application : one is by using a xml shape drawable, and applying it to the background of a button/edittext, the other is by using a canvas in a custom view.

I expect the result to be exactly the same, but it's not. You can see below the tiny difference between the respective strokes :

[image]

Both are round rectanlges with a 2dp stroke width, and a 8dp corners radius.
Here is the code for each of them :

Left, the drawable shape used as a background :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_cornersRadius"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/button_strokeWidth"
        android:color="@color/blue_light"/>
</shape>
```

Right, the onDraw method of the custom view :

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
canvas.drawPath(drawingPath,strokePaint);
canvas.drawText(text,demiWidth,textHeight,textPaint);
}
```

Whith :

```
    strokePaint     = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    strokePaint     .setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    strokePaint     .setStrokeWidth((int)(2*densityObtainedWithDisplayMetrics)));
    strokePaint     .setColor(the exact same as above);
```

And I observe tiny differences when displaying gradients with the same supposedly equivalent ways : The shape drawable has a nicer display, the colors look better, the lines are not blurred.

Could someone explain me why / how to work around it?
If I was to use only one way, it would be the second, but I don't want to since it doesn't look clean.
Thanks for any help!

EDIT :

Surprisingly, this difference occurs only when the stroke width of the custom layout is odd. With even values the display is exactly the same!

Comment: Try using `strokePaint.setDither(true);`. The `ShapeDrawable` may already be dithered by default. (Also, you could upload images to imgur or something, then post the link.)

Comment: It's in it, I didn't put it in the code because it doesn't change anything..

Comment: @Soxxeh : I put the picture on imgur : http://imgur.com/njzxD

Comment: @0gravity : Isn't it equivalent to
strokePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
?

Comment: @Charles yea that is why I deleted the comment. I usually use `strokePaint.setAntiAlias(true);` instead of the way you are doing it, but it should be the same. You can try it just to be safe :)

Comment: @0gravity Yes I tried, doesn't change anything, it would have been to easy right ;)
Actually I just tried without setting the antialiasing on, and the blur effect desappears, but the aliasing is really ugly..

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you take a look at the source for `GradientDrawable` (the object actually created from a `<shape>` XML tag) to see the draw calls that are put in place by the framework for the given shape created.

[GradientDrawable.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java)

You can see in the `inflate()` method how the XML is parsed out into the object, and then the method `draw()` is where all the pertient `Canvas` code is contained.

EDIT:  At quick glance, the only major difference I see is that the framework uses `canvas.drawRoundedRect()` instead of `canvas.drawPath()` when a single radius value is provided.  It also does it for both the fill and stroke, even though in your case the fill is transparent.  There may be other differences, I didn't trace all the code closely.

Comment: I wish I could mark your answer as useful, but I don't have 15 reputation.. I was actually wandering on GrepCode ShapeDrawable code.
Yes I tried the drawRoundRect and it doesn't change anything. It's wierd because if you look at the picture imgur.com/njzxD the antialising works the same on the corners, the difference is on the straight lines.
The only other difference I see is the use of
mStrokePaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
I don't know anything about colorfilers, and developer.android.com doesn't explain anything in the class reference..

Comment: Anybody knows How to display Text in Android Canvas ShapeDrawable with RectShape?